# Placeholder validation error - Contactform 7

Tags: wordpress, placeholder, contact-form

I am using placeholder text for my input fields and marking them as required, the form can be submitted without any text being entered.

It is obviously counting the placeholder text as a value which it should not. I have tried using "watermark" instead but this makes no difference.

I found a solution on stackoverflow:

Replace the following:

```
var submit = form.find('input:submit');
if (! submit.length) return; "
```

With:

```
var submit = form.find('input:submit');
if (! submit.length || submit == this.find('[placeholder]').wpcf7Placeholder()) return;"
```

This is fixing the issue but I also found that the responsive button is not displaying the menu options on click.

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: Can you show your Contact Form 7 code for how you're adding the placeholders to the inputs?

Comment: [text* name placeholder "Your name"][email* email placeholder "Your email"][text* subject placeholder "Subject"][textarea* message x6 placeholder "Requirement description"][submit "Send message"]